# Installing Devise on Engine brings route error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm having a problem creating an Engine in Rails.

I want to create an engine that uses Devise to share over all my other applications.

I followed the Getting Started guide for Engines at rails website:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Created an application, required my engine... everything runs just fine. 
Then, I run into Devise (I've already installed Devise direct in an application before, but not in an engine) but when I try to use it, by acessing any controller that inherits the `before_action authenticate_user!` I get this message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTv3k.jpg

I really don't understand (I'm starting in Ruby, I'm a CakePHP guy), the route is set, but it can't find it (?).

**engine/config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ...
  config.router_name = :doisbit
  config.parent_controller = 'Doisbit::ApplicationController'
end
```

**engine/config/routes.rb**

```
Doisbit::Engine.routes.draw do
  ...
  devise_for :users, class_name: "Doisbit::User", module: :devise
  ...
end
```

**engine/lib/doisbit/engine.rb**

```
module Doisbit
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Doisbit
  end
end
```

**engine/lib/doisbit.rb**

```
require 'doisbit/engine'
require 'devise'
...
```

**engine/doisbit.gemspec**

```
...
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  ...
  s.add_dependency "devise"
end
```

**engine/app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
module Doisbit
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

**application/config/routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  mount Doisbit::Engine, at: "/doisbit"
end
```

**application/config/environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
end
```

**application/Gemfile**

```
...
gem 'doisbit', path: "C:/.../doisbit"
...
```

## EDIT

Just noticed by accessing `/doisbit/users/sign_in` I get the form. (duh)

i.imgur.com/anTRK2d.jpg

But... still... by default it routes to `/users/sign_in` when i'm not logged in.

What I'm missing?